# Spin of cobalt-60

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

At many places in beta decay of cobalt-60, the ground state spin of the isotope is given as 5+. However that's not what is predicted by shell model and applying nordheim's strong rule. Is the data given purely experimental in such cases and outside purview of shell-model? Similarly, daughter nucleus Ni has 4+ spin-parity. 
Is there a theoretical way to determine the nuclear spins in ground state?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/454246/how-do-you-go-about-guessing-the-ground-state-spin-and-parity-of-a-nucleus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell Model arguments usually work well for nuclei close to magic neutron and proton numbers, but sometimes fail when that is not the case.  Co-60 is just not magic enough. Here is a link to an old paper that might help: http://ist-socrates.berkeley.edu/~schwrtz/PhysicsPapers/01PhysRev_94_95.pdf  The data in the nuclides chart is experiemntal and there is no theoretical model that explains all the measured gs spins, especially for the most challenging odd-odd isotopes.

Comment: The link is broken. It would be better to supply a journal reference, which can be found later if the link disappears.

Comment: @BenCrowell  After considerable searching I have been unable to locate the source material for the missing link.  I am as frustrated as you are.  From the name of the original link I infer that it was based on a paper published in Phys Rev C  in 1994-95.  I probably chose to display the linbk because the original article was behind a paywall.  It would have been preferable to quote both in my answer.